# difference between SNMP4J and Java Management extension package

Tags: java, snmp

What is the difference between SNMP4J and the Java Management extension (JMX) package provided by sun. I would like to develop a product for network mangement and monitoring. I want to select a better open source java snmp library. And I found these two options. Can somebody tell me which is the better one?

Answer (score 0):

Pummy,

```
  As per my knowledge, SNMP4J is the industry standard open source API for SNMP agent development and I would recommend that over JMX. Each has its own advantages and disadvantages. You need to google around to check out the advantages and disadvantages.
```

I would also recommend a wrapper around SNMP4J called Friendly-SNMP(I'm using this) which is much simpler to use but has one disadvantage and that is the lack of support for AgentX protocol. If you take that out of the equation, it is a very good API.

My Verdict : Friendly SNMP or SNMP4J.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now I am using SNMP4J Agent jar,but I can't able  to connect different agent at a time.Is it any way to run multiple agents concurrently using SNMP4J Agent jar?

Comment: No Pummy...you'll not be able to do so since when you start an agent, it will be bound to a port and when you try to start another instance, it'll not happen since the port will already be in use...